# How to hide the address bar in android app using trusted web activity

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps, android-app-signing

I have tried to convert codeigniter application into android app using trusted web activity .I have generated debug and release APK .I cannot hide address bar in app. I have put assetlinks.json file in .well known folder of application . It is not working .

This is my assetlinks.json

```
    [{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.consultantnext.dmatri",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["37:A8:DB:2C:EC:43:65:A9:3C:2A:60:88:16:8A:7A:07:BA:59:A7:7C:63:8C:57:4E:E2:52:40:46:DA:0E:65:AE"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://dmatri.consultantnext.com"
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.consultantnext.dmatri",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["37:A8:DB:2C:EC:43:65:A9:3C:2A:60:88:16:8A:7A:07:BA:59:A7:7C:63:8C:57:4E:E2:52:40:46:DA:0E:65:AE"]
  }
}]
```

I need to hide the address bar before uploading it into playstore.  How to hide the address bar?

Comment: What error or problem occurred that caused you to conclude: "It is not working.".

Comment: android app showing address bar.

Comment: Could be just a typo.. but I noticed that you wrote assertlinks.json above. It should be assetlinks.json

Comment: I have put assertlinks.json here  by mistake .But In .well-known folder the spelling is correct .assetlinks.json.